# Redirect website to Mobile version website using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mobile

HI i have used the following code to redirect to mobile website.It works fine from mobile to mobile website, domain.com to m.domain.com in mobile, but "?id=9" at the end of url is coming . How to remove the

```
 ?id=9
```

from the url .And how to redirect the mobile webiste m.domain.com from desktop browser to domain.com . The below code only redirect the website from mobile to mobile webiste m.domain.com

```
# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera  mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: If possible, please don't. Use Responsive Web Design instead.

Comment: ++ @PointedEars You could use Moderniz js along with media queries to find out if the device is mobile and YepNope js for conditional dynamic loading of JS and CSS files. If you detect that the device is mobile then the mobile JS, CSS will be loaded. Otherwise the desktop JS, CSS will be loaded. This way you have responsive design.

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis Modernizr requires client-side scripting. I recommend not to rely on client-side scripting. There is no need to find out if a device is a mobile device. You can use *only* media queries – plain CSS – to present the document properly on such a device. Then you can use scripting for the detection of support for special features, such as the Geolocation API. Again you do not need/should not use Modernizr for that.

Comment: @PointedEars The decision on whether to use a library such as Moderniz should be based on the application's specific characteristics and needs like the complexity of the app, development cycle time, feature detection needs like touch detection etc. So there isn't correct and wrong answer. It's up to the developers to select the tools that cover their applications unique needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strip query string append `?` in the target URL like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```

Comment: I copy  into htaccess  this code (also I change the last line with that on the answer). Can't see any change in the mobile version. do I have to make other settings?

Comment: This answer is specific to `strip query string` issue. Please post a new question with your issue and I will try to help you.

Comment: I cannot post a new question with the same content and subject, I will get ban. But, if you know the answer, I will vote your answer and you also get some points.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the way this platform works. I cannot post another answer here

Comment: ok, I post another question about this subject. If you have a good answer, please.. :)